# WhenTargetHas<> Binding Does not Work as Expected

Tags: ninject

I've got this class with this constructor:

```
public AbstractAddon([Configuration]object configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;
}
```

As you can see, it has a constructor parameter with `ConfigurationAttribute`.
`ConfigurationAttribute` is:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited=true)]
public class ConfigurationAttribute : Attribute { }
```

My Module is as:

```
public override void Load()
{
    this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .InheritedFrom(typeof(UIExtensibility.AbstractAddon))
        .BindAllBaseClasses()
        .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
    );

    this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>().WhenTargetHas<UIExtensibility.ConfigurationAttribute>();
}
```

and then, my `object` provider is:

```
private class AddonProvider : IProvider<object>
{

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        return "configuration settings";
    }

}
```

When I perform `kernel.GetAll<UIExtensibility.AbstractAddon>())`, i would expect the provider to be used to create the "configuration" `object` instances - but the provider is never called.

Could you help me, please?
I'll appreciate alot your help.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Have a look at the ninject `WhenTargetHas` source code and see where it looks for the attribute. Then check that the "demo" class inherited from `AddonProvider`. As I've mentioned before: *you cannot "inherit" parameter attributes to an overriding method - ever*. The concept doesn't apply here, whether you set `AttributeUsage.Inherited` to `true` or not doesn't matter at all. A constructor of an abstract base class is not inherited it's overridden.

Comment: So, I guess setting the `configuration` parameter as a field, it should be work? By another side, I could set the `ConfigurationAttribute` as class attribute on `AddonProvider`; so, how should I specify the binding as convention in this situation, so, how could I write down that: `I want that the string parameter is injected when their class contains the attribute 'x'`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what do you mean by "setting the 'configuration` parameter as a field"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attribute of a parameter is not "inherited" to a constructor of a deriving class. There's no inheriting taking place, instead the constructor of the deriving class is overriding (and extending) the constructor of the base class.

### Using an Inherited Class-Attribute Instead

You can use this instead:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true)]
public class ConfigurationAttribute : Attribute { }

[Configuration]
public abstract class AbstractAddon
{
    private readonly object configuration;

    protected AbstractAddon(object configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
}    

public class FooAddon : AbstractAddon
{
    public FooAddon(object configuration)
        : base(configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

and bindings:

```
this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(UIExtensibility.AbstractAddon))
    .BindAllBaseClasses()
    .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
);

this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>()
    .WhenClassHas<UIExtensibility.ConfigurationAttribute>
```

### Other Attribute-Based Methods

The [ninject wiki](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-the-built-in-attribute-based-helpers) also describes the other attribute based methods:

- `WhenTargetHas<SomeAttribute>` = checks if the parameter being injected into has the attribute
- `WhenTargetHas<SomeAttribute>` = checks whether the property being injected into has the attribute

Now properties and their attributes can be inherited, so this would be a possible solution:

```
public abstract class AbstractAddon
{
    [Inject]
    [Configuration]
    public object Configuration { get; set;}
}

this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>()
    .WhenMemberHas<ConfigurationAttribute>
```

### Attribute-Less Convention

Instead of checking for the attribute, since all of the types you want to inject the config into are deriving from `AbstractAddon` anyway, why not base the convention on that? Doesn't need an attribute at all.
I suspect this should work:

```
this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<AbstractAddon>();
```

If it doesn't work, you can just as well roll your own convention by using:

```
this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>()
    .When(... condition goes here...);
```

Comment: @Jordi glad i was of help. Could you please comment which solution you choose? And since it works it would be nice if you could mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark left to the voting arrows). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the first approach and it runs fine.

NInject module:

```
public class AddonsModule : Ninject.Modules.NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind(b => b.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
            .SelectAllClasses()
            .InheritedFrom(typeof(UIExtensibility.AbstractAddon))
            .BindAllBaseClasses()
            .Configure(c => c.InSingletonScope())
        );

        this.Bind<object>().ToProvider<ConfigurationProvider>().WhenClassHas<UIExtensibility.ConfigurationAttribute>();
    }

    private class ConfigurationProvider : IProvider<object>
    {

        public object Create(IContext context)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

And my Abstract class:

```
[Configuration]
public abstract class AbstractAddon : IAddon
{

    //...
}
```